# How did Dronacharya get his name "Drona"?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya

Drona is the guru of the Pandavas and the Kauravas. How did he get his name 'Drona'? What is the incident or reason which gave this specific name to him?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Droṇa* in Sanskrit means "bucket" (or something like it - not sure of the nuance here). Per the [Monier Williams Sanskrit-English Dictionary](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/monier/):

> n. (fr. 4. द्रु) a wooden vessel , bucket , trough &c ; a सोम vessel ([cf. Zd. draona]) RV. MBh. &c (ifc. f(आ). Hcat. )

It is said that Drona was born from a bucket, and that that is how he got his name:

> And as it came out, he [Bharadwaja] held it in a pot (drana), and of that fluid thus preserved in a pot was born a son who came to be called Drona (the pot-born).

Source: *Mahabharata*, book 1 (Adi Parva), section 168 (part of the Chaitraratha Parva), using the Ganguli translation.

Comment: How do you use that dictionary. I enter many wordsbut it says not found

Comment: @GovindBalaji You have to enter text using their somewhat unusual transliteration system. To find the entry I quoted above, you should enter `droNa` (case-sensitive).

Comment: @senshin did Drona born without Ovum?

Answer (score 5):

Droṇa implies that he was not gestated in a womb, but outside the human body in a droṇa (vessel or a basket). We do know this in another name, as **test tube babies**.

Comment: That's not how test tube babies are grown. The baby still develops in the mother's body. It is only fertilized in a test tube. Drona was gestated outside the body. Test tube babies are gestated in the mothers body.  http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/262798.php

Comment: Did he born without ovum?