# How did Sagara have 60,000 children?

Tags: ramayana, puranas, ganga

The story of the descent of Ganga is very well known. King Sagara's 60,000 sons were burnt to ashes by their own sin of insulting Lord Kapila, and to offer redemption to them, their nephew's grandson Bhagiratha brought down the Ganga to the earth.

But my question is more fundamental. How come Sagara had 60,000 children with Sumati (even though she was Garuda's sister she couldn't have had such magical powers)? And that too when his other wife Keshini had only one son Asamanjasa?

Comment: @sv. Well, Kapila is an avatara of Vishnu, so just like we say Lord Rama, Lord Krsna, I said Lord Kapila.

Comment: @sv. The story of Kapila is told in the last ten or so chapters of third Skanda (canto) of the Srimad Bhagavatam: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3 Also, you may be interested in this fictional dialogue I wrote: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ev0XgyKjqu1iktUfgRIWhXnjor6KoWOuvRiGCb9_AYU/edit?usp=sharing It explores the question of why Kapila would invent a philosophy that doesn't acknowledge the existence of a supreme being, when Kapila himself was an incarnation of Vishnu.

Comment: @Keshav I do not know what you meant by ''doesn't acknowledge the existence of a supreme being.'' Throughout those chapters in the Bhagavatam he connects all his teachings to Bhagavan and Bhakti. Then how do you make this statement?

Comment: @Surya Yeah, it's true that Kapila's teachings in the Srimad Bhagavatam are heavily Bhakti-laden, but historically the Samkhya school didn't believe in Bhakti or a supreme being. They just believed that there was a bunch of different Purushas or souls, and then there was Prakriti or matter/energy.  They didn't believe in a notion of Ishwara.  The Yoga school of Patanjali, by the way, accepted the basic Samkhya worldview, but it also accepted the existence of one very special Purusha, known as Ishwara.

Comment: @Surya By the way, see the Brahma Sutras for Vyasa's refutation of Samkhya: http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm (Just do ctrl F for all the instances of the word "pradhana".) In any case, Prabhupada reconciles Kapila's Bhakti-centric teachings in the Bhagavatam with the fact that the Samkhya school was atheistic by saying that there were two different Kapilas! He claims that Vishnu's incarnation Kapila propounded a Bhakti-centric Samkhya system, but then some later "evil" guy named Kapila invented an atheistic Samkhya system.  I don't buy it though.

Comment: @Keshav But then what Kapila says would be final right? So if **he** talks about Bhakti then shouldn't that be the Mukhya kurikkol of his philosophy?

Comment: @Surya Well, the problem is that if you look at Kapila's separate Samkhya writings, they're atheistic.  So you could say he told his Mom one thing and the rest of the world another thing, or that it's an interpolation in the Bhagavatam, etc.  In any case, you may find my fictional dialogue linked to above interesting. By the way, it looks like Prabhupada's two-Kapilas theory comes from the earlier Gaudiya Acharya Baladeva's commentary on the Brahma Sutras; see page 16 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=gfHRFz6lU2kC&lpg=PA16&ots=JzF6tijvoW&dq=kapila%20atheist&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Surya By the way, outside of the Srimad Bhagavatam, I don't think any other scriptures say that Kapila's philosophy was related to Bhakti.

Comment: @Keshav To be frank Baladeva's reasoning sounds convincing.

Comment: @Surya I think it's completely unconvincing; like I said apart from the Srimad Bhagavatam there are no texts that say that Kapila's system was Bhakti-centric, and as far as I know there are no scriptures that say that there are two different Kapilas.  Also, like I said there is already a name for Samkhya + the notion of a supreme being: the Yoga school.  What distinguishes Samkhya from Yoga is precisely the question of whether Ishwara exists

Comment: @Surya It looks like Adi Shankaracharya also suggests that there are two Kapilas: "The scriptural passage which the pûrvapakshin has quoted as proving the eminence of Kapila's knowledge would not justify us in believing in such doctrines of Kapila (i.e. of some Kapila) as are contrary to Scripture; for that passage mentions the bare name of Kapila (without specifying which Kapila is meant), and we meet in tradition with another Kapila, viz. the one who burned the sons of Sagara and had the surname Vâsudeva." http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34140.htm I'm still skeptical.

Comment: @Surya Here's definitive evidence that there's only one Kapila: verse 70 of the Samkhya Karika says "This foremost purifying doctrine, the sage (Kapila) imparted to Asuri out of compassion; Asuri taught it to Panchashikha, by whom this doctrine was propounded extensively."  http://i.imgur.com/8VEHyy3.jpg And the Srimad Bhagavatam says "The fifth incarnation, named Lord Kapila, is foremost among perfected beings. He gave an exposition of the creative elements and metaphysics to Āsuri Brāhmaṇa, for in course of time this knowledge had been lost." http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

King Sagara who being childless propitiated the saint Bhrigu by penances extending over a hundred years. The saint, pleased with Sāgara's worship said that from one wife of his, he will have a son from whom his heir and  maintainer of lineage and from other, 60,000 sons will be born, but he didn't specify who among Kesini or Sumati will get what.

Later, in [Ramayana (XXXIX)](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rama/ry039.htm), Viswamitra says to Rama:

> Then Sumati, the younger, gave
>
> Birth to a gourd, O hero brave,
>
> Whose rind, when burst and cleft in two,
>
> Gave sixty thousand babes to view.
>
> All these with care the nurses laid
>
> In jars of oil; and there they stayed,
>
> Till, youthful age and strength complete,
>
> Forth speeding from each dark retreat,
>
> All peers in valour, years, and might,
>
> The sixty thousand came to light.

It's clear that Sumati didn't give birth to 60,000 sons through natural process. As it happened with Gandhari, Sumati's sons had a miraculous birth.

Comment: +1. Interesting question.
I think the children can't logically be born by the natural process, that's why called _maansas putra_.

Comment: @ABcDexter They weren't born through ordinary means, but they weren't Manas Putras either, they were born in a manner analogous to how the Kauravas were born, which I discuss in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3282/36

Comment: Quite poetic translation

Answer (score 1):

*As discussed [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp096.htm) in Vishnu Purana about Sagara's 60000 sons.*

> SUMATI the daughter of Kaśyapa, and Kesiní the daughter of Rája Viderbha, were the two wives of Sagara 1. Being without progeny, the king solicited the aid of the sage Aurva with great earnestness, and the Muni pronounced this boon, that one wife should bear one son, the upholder of his race, and the other should give birth to sixty thousand sons; and he left it to them to make their election. Kesiní chose to have the single son; Sumati the multitude: and it came to pass in a short time that the former bore Asamanjas 2, a prince through whom the dynasty continued; and the daughter of Vinatá (Sumati) had sixty thousand sons.

From Another [Source](http://haribhakt.com/ancient-indians-defied-natural-process-of-giving-births-proofs-of-transdimensional-science-in-hindu-texts/)

*According to history of Ramayan, Ikshvaku dynasty’s king Sagar had two queens  – Keshini and Sumati. After remaining childless for several years, King and both Queens went to Himalay to perform strict penance and abide by the Vedic rituals of obtaining child through unborn process.
Maharishi Bhrigu blessed them that Sumati will give birth to 60,000 haughty sons and Keshini will give birth to a son whose son will continue the lineage.
As years passed, Sumati gave birth to pumpkin sized Garbh pind. Raja Sagar was not amused, he was about to throw it away, he heard Akashvani that “the Garbh Pind has 60,000 fertile seeds. You need to keep each seed in a ghee filled 60,000 separate pots.”
Raja Sagar obeyed the Akashvani thanking Bhagwan Shiv for his blessings. In due period, the pots gave birth to 60,000 sons of Sumati.
Later King Sagar thought of performing Ashwamedh  Yagya, he asked all his 60,000 sons to protect the horse and make the Yagya successful.
While that Ashwamedh horse is being moved around provinces it reached the south-easterly zone, and at seashore Indra abducted that horse and hid it underneath the earth. Raja Sagar then ordered his escorting sons that horse to dig up that place to locate the ritual horse. Then those princes unremittingly dug the place to oceanic depths until they reached Shrihari reposing there in the form of Sage Kapil.
When the 60,000 sons found the horse at Kapil dev’s ashram, they thought he had stolen it. When they prepared to attack the meditating rishi, Kapil opened his eyes, fire emanated, and they were immediately burned to ashes.*

Comment: Conflicting stories. First story says sage [Aurva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurva) granted the boon to King Sagara and the second says [Bhrigu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhrigu). The latter one is from [Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga38/balasans38.htm#Verse6).

Comment: @sv hinduism is littered with conflicting stories.