# Where are drona and shiva used as meters, what other meters are there similarly?

Tags: history, sri-vaishnava, sanskrit, terminology

I learned recently about Koorathaazhvar and Kulothunga Chola's apparent argument, although I'm not interested in the context it was used, I'm curious about the question, as what and when are these meters(drona, shiva)used, and what other such meters are there?

Comment: This question is primarily associated with songs and poetry and ragas  and little to do  with Hinduism. So am not sure if this is valid question for he site or not.

Comment: Does the poster  mean "measure" when the says "meter"?

Comment: This is a linguistic question and should be closed @SwiftPushkar

Answer (score 3):

The measurements Drona appear in many ancient texts. Dronacharya, who is the teacher of Kauravas and Pandavas was named [after a bucket or a wooden vessel](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/354/5212).

When Krimikanta Chola asks to sign a document saying there is no one higher than Shiva, Kurathalzhwan adds a line but Drona is higher. Here, Koorathazhwan was meaning the measurements.

There are certain measurements given in an ancient Ayurveda texts named *Ṣoḍaśāṅgahṛdayam*. From [wisdomlib.org](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/drona#ayurveda)

> Guñjā (Raktikā) = 1 seed of Guñjā
>   8 Raktikā = 1 Māṣa (1 gram)
>   10 Māṣa = 1 Karṣa (10 grams)
>   2 Karṣa = 1 Śukti (20 grams)
>   2 Śukti = 1 Pala (40 grams)
>   2 Pala = 1 Prasṛta (80 grams)
>   2 Prasṛta = 1 Kuḍava (Añjali) (160 grams)
>   2 Kuḍava = 1 Śarāva (320 grams)
>   2 Śarāva = 1 Prastha (640 grams)
>   4 Prastha = 1 Āḍhaka (Pātra) (2.56 kilograms)
>   **4 Āḍhaka = 1 Droṇa (10.24 kilograms)**
>   4 Droṇa = 1 Droṇī (40.96 kilograms)
>   100 Pala = 1 Tulā (4 kilograms).

When it comes to measurement named Shiva, it is lot smaller than Drona. It corresponds to a measurement of a peg. [Monier Williams Dictionary gives](https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/awork/apidev/simple-search/v1.0/list-0.2s.html) one of the many definitions. The related one to measurements is

> a peg, L.  [ID=217521]

But I couldn't find exactly in which text this measurement is given.

Comment: @Naren You are welcome. You may upvote questions and answers you have found helpful. If my answer has addressed your queries, you can click on tick mark below the answer. Also take a [tour] of our site.

Comment: Although the questioner has said explicitly that he is not interested in the Siva-hatred fairy tale (that has no historical basis) this poster has put it in.

Comment: "krimikanta chola" is hate speech against a great historical king.

Comment: @SK It is not a hate speech. It is one of the names I have not gone into details on what happened in the conversation of Koorathazhwan and Chozha king. We should give context of what is the answer about. Apparently, some users misunderstood what OP said in the question by meter. OP meant measurement only.

Comment: @SK Hate speech against a king who murdered 2 pious, learned Brahmanas? What's next, hate speech against Hitler, against Stalin, by calling them evil?